# How to populate a select dropdown using array received from $http response in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate a select dropdown using Months and Day values that are two separate arrays within a date.json file. My code for controller is as below

```
var app = angular.module("profileApp",[]);

app.controller("dobController",function($scope,$http){
$scope.dob={};

$http.get('date.json')
.then(function(response){
    $scope.months=[];
    dob = response.data;
    months=dob.Months;
}, function(response){
     alert("Error in response");
});
```

My problem is even though the response from the http service is received properly (I can successfully log the Months array value from the response), I cannot populate my select dropdown and it remains blank. HTML as below

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="dobController">
  <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Date of Birth:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select ng-model="birthday" ng-options="option for option in months">{{months}}</select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My date.json file

```
{
"Months" : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
"Days" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `for option`. Try `option in months` instead for a simple array

Comment: Tried it. Think it violated the syntax rule for the ng-options directive and the dropdown is still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this,

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="month as month for month in months">
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/jGOX2nCJfexddiOC9lGR?p=preview)

Comment: Yes it worked. I made the controller changes according to your's. Although what still baffles me is why didn't my controller work. Thanks!